# Make a PhoneGap/Cordova project suitable for Android version 4.2.2

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, phonegap

This may seem like a crazy requirement but I'm trying to create a Cordova application which will run without issues on an Android device with version 4.2.2.

It is to run on a Clover Station, and the Android version cannot be upgraded. Currently, the entire Clover network (separate to Google Play) has all Clover Stations installed with this version of Android, so my hands are tied.

I'm having a problem communicating via Ajax with our back end, and this does not happen when testing the app on my iPad, or my iPhone, or in a browser. I don't have a more up to date Android device to test with so I'm assuming the issue is the Android Version.

I don't know enough about Cordova to know whether you can install the Android platform for a specific version of Android. Ive read countless SO questions/answers about this .. but I confess I'm a bit lost.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about the issue? You only say "a problem", what does this mean exactly? Are you debugging the app properly with Visual Studio 2017? Try it because it will run the app and debug it in realtime, allowing you to see errors and the console output. Then, edit your question to provide more info.

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio, I do have Android Studio. The code is written in an editor (Komodo) and the PhoneGap app creates the Android/iOS platform code. When I test on my tablets with the PhoneGap Developers App - in iOS I can get data from the server via AJAX .. on the Android tablet I get nothing. But I don't know how I can check what's happening on the Tablet.   I'll install Visual Studio.

Comment: I stopped using external editors for Cordova apps when I switched to VS, it allows you to manage plugins and all the JS, HTML and CSS code. Add console.log output to check from the console that your code is being executed properly, and watch the console output on debug mode. Android Studio is not a good idea for Cordova apps because it is totally unaware of the Cordova app structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This may seem like a crazy requirement but I'm trying to create a Cordova application which will run without issues on an Android device with version 4.2.2.

The following link shows that basically every cordova android platform version should support devices running Android 4.2.x out of the box:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#requirements-and-support

Run the following to check which android platform version is installed:

```
cordova platform ls
```

Perhaps if it's really old, you can try to upgrade and hope for bug fixes in cordova-android to fix your issue. You can also experiment with downgrading. To do this, you can

```
cordova plugin save
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@5.0.0
```

Or whatever version you want to use.

Also make sure to install the required Android API levels in your Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go at your suggestion.